# Did the goal to liberate souls from the Imprisoned Afterlife mean an end to Military Industrial Sorcery?

Tags: the-red-star, chris-gossett

In *The Red Star* series, magic is introduced in the form of "Military Industrial Sorcery," essentially a form of magic engineered into the normal rote techniques of nearly every modern soldier throughout the world, transforming every trained soldier into a sorcerer armed with modern technology and weaponry to amplify their power.

Unbeknownst to most, however, is the fact that this magic is actually powered by human souls trapped in the Imprisoned Afterlife.  It is a secret kept only by the leaders of the world so the ability to contain the souls of the dead and transform them into Post-Human Energy, the source for magic, is limited only to a few elite circle of people in power.

The story of *The Red Star* then follows the adventures of Maya and Marcus Antares, as Marcus apparently dies in battle, only to be saved in the afterlife by the Red Woman who spirits him away into the otherworldly Spiritrealm.

After receiving a strange message from Marcus from beyond the grave, Maya comes to hatch a plan to follow Marcus into the Spiritrealm, save him from the afterlife, and free all of the Imprisoned souls.

Would Maya and her crew freeing the imprisoned souls bring an end to magic, and would they be aware of this?

Comment: There are lots of people trying to work themselves out of a living.

Comment: Haha. At least she’s doing it for love.